# Pass parameter of current object into create method Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Instead of having to create a separate controller for nested attributes such as this:

```
def new
    @map = @account.maps.build
end

def create
    @map = @account.maps.create(params[:map].permit(:))
end
```

How can I pass the parameter of `account_id` to the create method in the `maps` controller rather than creating a whole seperate controller for `accounts_maps`?

**For example:**

If I am creating a map under this url: `http://localhost:3000/accounts/1/maps/new`
I need the account_id of the map to be 1 when it is created. How can this be achieved?

Comment: are you using nested attributes?

Comment: Yes, I am using nested attributes.

Comment: did you check `accept_nested_attributes_for`

Answer (score 1):

If you had a route defined like this in routes.rb

```
resources :accounts do
  resources :maps
end
```

the url would be http://localhost:3000/accounts/17/maps, and you could access account id with

```
params[:account_id]
```

which would be 17 in this case. Also, @account.maps.build automatically adds account_id to map, what you might be missing is declaring @account.

In your example, you could do

```
before_action :find_account

def new
  @map = @account.maps.build
end

def create
  @map = Map.create(map_params)
end

private

def find_account
  @account = Account.find(params[:account_id])
end

def map_params
  params.require(:map).permit(:name, :account_id) #permit all map params
end
```